# parsing quotes with node commander

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, node-commander

I'm writing a command line interface using node commander, and am stuck on parsing single quotes within an argument. I've searched the documentation and StackOverflow, and haven't found anything conclusive.

Is there a way to pass in an argument which contains single quotes?

---

Abstracting away what I know works, what I'm left with is a CLI where running:

```
node test.js command 'value''s values'
```

with the following program (credit [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.com/writing-command-line-applications-in-nodejs-2cf8327eee2), used for the sake of a simple, functioning example):

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict';

const program = require('commander');
program
    .version('0.0.1')
    .command('command <req> [optional]')
    .action(function(req,optional){
        console.log('User passed %s', req);
    });
program.parse(process.argv);
```

The result is `User passed values values`, which is missing the single quote from the first word of the argument. The desired output is `User passed value's values`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the apostrophe. This will work:

`node test.js command 'value'\''s values'`

This works because of something called "strong quoting". You can read more about it [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting#strong_quoting).

Strong quoting means that this will work as well:

`node test.js command "value's values"`

Comment: Hmm!  Shame on me -- I'd tried this with the broader program and it didn't wouldn't work there, but it looks like it's an issue with the scripting that created the actual command, rather than with the parsing of the command's argument.  Thanks!